# CentOS 7 teamed bridge network only works on single NIC

Tags: centos, networking, networkmanager, bridge, bonding

I've been trying for several days to get my server NICs teamed, and then bridged to be used on a virtualization box (KVM). I've managed to get it on the network and at least pinging google, however, it only works when I'm plugged in to the second NIC (eno2). If I've got the cable only in the first NIC (eno1) the server isn't seen by my router on my local network.

I've looked at the documentation, and countless forums. I found the best resource that has gotten me the 'closest' was this site: https://myredhatcertification.com/2015/04/09/software-bridge-on-top-of-the-teaming-device/. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. As an aside, my KVM VMs do not have network using either of the NICs. However, that can be looked at after I get the network up and reliable on the host.

I've got NetworkManager stopped and disabled (but still installed).

Here are the relevant outputs and files (please ask if you want to see more)

ip a s
This is when the network cable has is plugged into eno2

```
[root@server1 ~]# ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:3b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feca:3b6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master team0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:3b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feca:3b6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:58:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:58:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brteam0 state UP
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:3b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feca:3b6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: brteam0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ca:3b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.150/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global brteam0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feca:3b6e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

brctl show

```
[root@server1 ~]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id   STP enabled interfaces
brteam0   8000.0cc47aca3b6e no    team0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-brteam0

```
DEVICE=brteam0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR0=192.168.0.150
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=192.168.0.1
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0

```
DEVICE=brteam0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR0=192.168.0.150
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=192.168.0.1
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0
DEVICE=team0
TEAM_CONFIG="{\"runner\":{\"name\":\"loadbalance\"}}"
DEVICETYPE=Team
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=team0
UUID=1ddbb7ce-4a40-43b3-8394-7629bc9074a9
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
BRIDGE=brteam0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0-port1

```
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=team0-port1
UUID=310074ca-cf54-43b9-b7e4-8d25b74274af
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0-port2

```
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=team0-port2
UUID=ad6972fa-94df-4c1c-9241-5315c823f4b9
DEVICE=eno2
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

If anyone can see a mistake or I've missed a critical step please let me know. All help is appreciated.